# Green DAO relationship

Tags: android, greendao, greendao-generator

This is my code :

```
 Schema schema = new Schema(1, "com.core.greendao.db");

    /* Topic Model Table */
    Entity topic = schema.addEntity("Topic");
    topic.addLongProperty("topic_id").primaryKey();
    topic.addStringProperty("group_id").notNull();
    topic.addStringProperty("user_id");
    topic.addStringProperty("slug");
    topic.addStringProperty("message");
    topic.addStringProperty("reply_count");
    topic.addStringProperty("like_count");
    topic.addStringProperty("anon_status");
    topic.addStringProperty("link_data");
    topic.addStringProperty("created_at");
    topic.addStringProperty("locale");
    topic.addIntProperty("status");

    /* Reply Model Table */
    //TODO: Topic id add for relation
    Entity reply = schema.addEntity("Replies");
    reply.addLongProperty("reply_id").primaryKey();
    reply.addStringProperty("message");
    reply.addStringProperty("reply_count");
    reply.addStringProperty("like_count");
    reply.addStringProperty("anon_status");
    reply.addStringProperty("link_data");
    reply.addStringProperty("created_at");
    reply.addStringProperty("locale");
    reply.addIntProperty("status");

    /* User Model Table */
    //TODO: Topic id to add for relation
    Entity user = schema.addEntity("User");
    user.addIdProperty();
    user.addLongProperty("user_id");
    user.addStringProperty("url");
    user.addStringProperty("fullname");
    user.addStringProperty("tagline");
    user.addStringProperty("image");
    user.addStringProperty("category_title");

    /* Actions */
    //TODO: Topic id and Reply id for relation
    Entity actions = schema.addEntity("Actions");
    actions.addIdProperty();
    actions.addLongProperty("user_id");
    actions.addStringProperty("url");


    /*******************************************************************/

    Property topicIdForTopicUser = user.addLongProperty("topic_id").notNull().getProperty();
    user.addToOne(topic, topicIdForTopicUser);

    Property topicIdForTopicAction = actions.addLongProperty("topic_id").notNull().getProperty();
    actions.addToOne(topic, topicIdForTopicAction);

    Property topicIdForReply = reply.addLongProperty("topic_id").notNull().getProperty();
    reply.addToOne(topic, topicIdForReply);


    /*******************************************************************/
```

As per the structure, `topic_id` is a **primary key** in the `Topic` table and is **foreign key** in the `User`, `Action`, and `Replies` tables.

I am getting proper values from the `Topic` table. But getting null point when I try to get values from other table on the basis of `topic_id`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.addToOne(table, property)` method to specify the relationship. You also don't need to specify the id for the object, you can just use `.addIdProperty()` For example

```
Schema schema = new Schema(1, "com.core.greendao.db");
Entity user = schema.addEntity("User");
user.addIdProperty();

Entity topic = schema.addEntity("Topic");
topic.addIdProperty();
Property userId = topic.addLongProperty("user_id").notNull().getProperty()
topic.addToOne(user, userId);
```

See [GreenDAO docs](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/) for more examples of relationships.